# This "Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering" is not found in Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics10.0.3

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, datasource, sitecore-mvc

We are in the process of converting Sitecore 9.0.2 MVC project to Sitecore 10.0.3. The following code was used to convert the shorthand like `site:$datafolder/Home/Banne` to the absolute path in the context of the current location. This way we were able to copy and paste the renderings without making changes in the datasource path.

After moving this code to Sitecore 10.0.3 we are not able to find the following namespace in the `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.dll` version 10.0.3
`Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering`

```
<mvc.customizeRendering>
    <processor type="Common.Pipelines.mvc.customizeRendering.DatasourceResolver, Common" patch:after="*"/>
</mvc.customizeRendering>
```

```
using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.ResolveRenderingDatasource;

namespace Common.Pipelines.mvc.customizeRendering
{
    public class DatasourceResolver : CustomizeRenderingProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
        {
            var _rootPath = Sitecore.Context.Site.SiteInfo.RootPath.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rootPath) && _rootPath.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/SiteFolder/SiteCollections"))
            {
                var rendering = args.Rendering;
                var renderingDatasourceArgs = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(rendering.DataSource);
                CorePipeline.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", renderingDatasourceArgs);
                rendering.DataSource = renderingDatasourceArgs.Datasource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inherit from `CustomizeRenderingProcessor` but you never call any `base` method. It means you don't need this inheritance.

Instead, inherit from `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcPipelineProcessor<Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingArgs>` like:

```
public class DatasourceResolver : MvcPipelineProcessor<Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingArgs>
{
    public override void Process(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
    {
        var _rootPath = Sitecore.Context.Site.SiteInfo.RootPath.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rootPath) && _rootPath.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/SiteFolder/SiteCollections"))
        {
            var rendering = args.Rendering;
            var renderingDatasourceArgs = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(rendering.DataSource);
            CorePipeline.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", renderingDatasourceArgs);
            rendering.DataSource = renderingDatasourceArgs.Datasource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marek,
"CustomizeRenderingArgs" is not available in the "Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics" version 10.0.3.
Please know that the code provided in my question working fine in sitecore 9.0.2.

Comment: `CustomizeRenderingArgs` is in namespace `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering` in `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc`. Answer updated

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly decompile 10.3 dlls and it confirms.

[image]

`Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering` Deprecated in Sitecore 10.0. Please use `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingProcessor` and it is part of `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc` instead.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thanks