# Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics 10.3 doesn't contain a definition for Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering

Tags: sitecore-api

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.ResolveRenderingDatasource;

public class CustomMVCResolveRenderingDataSource : CustomizeRenderingProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
    {
        var rendering = args.Rendering;
        //Get the Site Item
        var contextSiteItem = GetSiteItem(Context.Item);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rendering.DataSource) && contextSiteItem != null)
        {
            if (rendering.DataSource.Contains("$SiteName"))
            {
                rendering.DataSource = rendering.DataSource.Replace("$SiteName", contextSiteItem.Name);
                Item sourceItem = Context.Database.GetItem(rendering.DataSource);
                if (sourceItem != null)
                {
                    rendering.DataSource = sourceItem.ID.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        //Initialize the resolved DataSource to ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs
        var renderingDSArgs = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(rendering.DataSource);
        CorePipeline.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", renderingDSArgs);
        rendering.DataSource = renderingDSArgs.Datasource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This "Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering" is not found in Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics10.0.3](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35799/this-sitecore-mvc-analytics-pipelines-response-customizerendering-is-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitecore 10.3 `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering` logic is moved to `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc` dll

`Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering` use this

Comment: Thanks for sharing it just works fine now...

Answer (score 3):

In Sitecore 10.3 `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering` namespace no longer exists.

All the logic is moved to `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc` dll, including:

- `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingArgs`
- `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingProcessor`
- `Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.Personalize`